# Flutte Floor: There are no type converts defined even though the @TypeConverters annotation is used

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

everything was working fine until last build, where it displays the following error:

```
[INFO] Running build...
[SEVERE] floor_generator:floor_generator on lib/db/app_database.dart:

There are no type converts defined even though the @TypeConverters annotation is used.
package:apoce/db/app_database.dart:24:16
   ╷
24 │ abstract class AppDatabase extends FloorDatabase {
   │                ^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
[INFO] Running build completed, took 1.3s

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 53ms
```

I'm not sure why it's showing this error, I googled for a while but it appears no one has got same at first glance.
My database class is:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:apoce/db/FormFieldsDao.dart';
import 'package:apoce/db/FormsDao.dart';
import 'package:apoce/db/HashDao.dart';
import 'package:apoce/db_converters/list_choices.converter.dart';
import 'package:apoce/db_converters/list_fieldsets.converter.dart';
import 'package:apoce/db_converters/list_questions.converter.dart';
import 'package:apoce/db_converters/list_string.converter.dart';
import 'package:apoce/models/FormFields.dart';
import 'package:apoce/models/Forms.dart';
import 'package:apoce/models/Question.dart';
import 'package:apoce/models/choice.dart';
import 'package:apoce/models/hash.dart';
import 'package:floor/floor.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sqflite;

part 'app_database.g.dart'; // the generated code will be there

@TypeConverters([
  StringListConverter,
  FiledSetsListConverter,
  QuestionsListConverter,
  ChoicesListConverter,
])
@Database(version: 5, entities: [Forms, FormFields, Hashes, Question, Choice])
abstract class AppDatabase extends FloorDatabase {
  //static Future<AppDatabase> openDatabase() async => _$open();
  FormsDao get formsDao;
  FormFieldsDao get formFieldsDao;
  HashDao get hashDao;
}
```

My pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  floor: ^0.17.0
  dio: ^3.0.10
  freezed: ^0.12.2
  flutter_bloc: ^6.1.1

dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: '0.40.4'
```

Thank you.